# Is there a way to programmatically get the description of Azure AD client keys?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-active-directory, azureportal, azure-ad-powershell-v2

I used powershell's AzureRm module to retrieve a list of keys for an Azure AD application using the command "Get-AzureRmADAppCredential" but the object returned only contains the StartDate, EndDate, KeyId and Type which I understand matches up with the application manifest. However, when you go to settings -> Keys from the Azure web portal there is also a "Description" field. I want to know if there is a way to get this description field as well.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PowerShell commands is using the Azure AD Graph REST actually, however this field is not public in Azure AD Graph. Please check the metadata about [PasswordCredential](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#passwordcredential-type):

[image]

And this field also doesn't exposed from [Microsoft Graph-PasswordCredential](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/passwordcredential). So I am afraid, you are not able to get the description field at present. You may submit the feedback about the Graph API from [this site](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) if you have this requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Since it is not available in any of the APIs. I'm going to try a bit of a hacky solution and try to use the same request that the Azure Web portal is using, as that response does contain the description field.